# Django Call method in template and use the return (,,)

Tags: python, django, templates

I Guys, 
I begin with Django, I would like an object to return its statistics and displays them directly in the HTML template.
For that, my object method. get_stat (self) returns a list and 3 dictionary.
How can I use these data returned? I can see the array in the method call {{}} I can not use them in {% %} and use them in the Javasript to make chart.
How to get back his array for use it?

Thank you in advance for your clarification

My Model:

```
class Adviser(models.Model):    
    TYPES_CHOICES = (('PRF', _('Professor')),
       ('MGR', _('Manager')),)


   def get_stat(self):
       some queries to create tables

       return (list_stat1,tab_stat1,tab_stat2,tab_stat3)
```

In my template HTML:

```
        {% for adviser in advisers %}

          
            {{ adviser }}     
            {{ adviser.type }}
            {% adviser.get_stat as adviser_list_stat1 adviser_tab_stat1 adviser_tab_stat2 adviser_tab_stat3 %}
          
        {% endfor %}
```

With this :

```
{{ adviser.get_stat }}
```

I have my tab :
([2, 1, 0, 1, 0], {'Cours xy': 1}, {}, {'cours xx': 5})

Comment: It looks like this might be a good case for a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_stat(self) should return  a dictionary {"list_1":[2, 1, 0, 1, 0], "dict_1":{'Cours xy': 1}}  and then you can do:

```
{% for adviser in advisers %}
   {% with ad_stat=adviser.get_stat %}
      {{ad_stat.list_1}}
      {{ad_stat.dict_1}}
      ....
   {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes it is something like I need. But now I get the error Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:  

'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Answer (score 0):

Define your method `get_stat` as a property to call it in template:

```
class Adviser(models.Model):    
    TYPES_CHOICES = (('PRF', _('Professor')),
       ('MGR', _('Manager')),)


    @property
    def get_stat(self):
        some queries to create tables

        return (list_stat1,tab_stat1,tab_stat2,tab_stat3)
```

Now you can call it in template:

```
{% for adviser in advisers %}
    {{ adviser.get_stat }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi, I added @property, but my method works because it already turned around my table. example table ([2, 1, 0, 1, 0], { 'xy Course': 1}, {}, {'course xx': 5})

Comment: Hi, my objective is to recover the 4 variables to exploit them, how teh template tag can help me ?

Comment: @user2274064 in that case you can simply call it one by one: `{{ adviser.get_stat.0 }}` -> `[2, 1, 0, 1, 0]`, `{{ adviser.get_stat.1 }}` -> `{'Cours xy': 1}`, ...

Comment: the only problem I see is that that the function should be called 4 times (4 times queries on the same DB) to get the 4 tables...